# select info from dbs and delete (not working)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have this query:

```
DELETE FROM amx_admins_servers, amx_amxadmins
WHERE
  amx_admins_servers.admin_id = (SELECT id FROM amx_amxadmins WHERE username='kokoz') 
  AND amx_amxadmins.username = 'kokoz'
```

but didnt work.

I get sql error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE amx_admins_servers.admin_id = (SELECT id FROM
>   amx_amxadmins WHERE username' at line 2

where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to delete an admin user and all its entries in the server table. Use

```
DELETE a, s 
FROM amx_amxadmins a
inner join amx_admins_servers s on a.id = s.admin_id
WHERE a.username='kokoz'
```